# drawing pre-order, post-order and in-order tree

Tags: inorder, preorder, postorder

The rule for drawing pre-order, post-order and in-order is:

1. pre-order traversal: root, left, right
2. post-order traversal: left, right, root
3. in-order traversal: left root, right

If for example we have expression like this:

**ABCDEFGHIJKL,**

How can I draw (pre-order, post-order and and in-order) separately for this expression.
It’s possible we have different form of tree for each (pre-order, post-order and and in-order). (i.e two forms of pre-order).
 We just can have unique tree if we have both (pre-order and and in-order) or (post-order and in-order).
in pre-order the first node is root (i.e "A" is root).
in post-order the last node is root (i.e "L" is root).

Is there any overall formula or “rule” for drawing these trees? I cannot draw them

EDIT: I mean how to construct tree from each pre-order, post-order and in-order of the following traversal:

ABCDEFGHIJKL,

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here.  Are you asking how to reconstruct a tree from e.g. preorder+in order?

Comment: Yes, I mean how to construct tree from each pre-order, post-order and in-order of the following traversal:

ABCDEFGHIJKL,

Comment: You cannot construct **the** tree if you only know one of these.  You can construct **a** tree, but that's trivial.  (For instance, a valid solution for pre-order is `A->B->C->D->...`)